# Problema ao redirecionar página, após a impressão usando jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Galera estou dando um `window.print();` para imprimir minha página, logo após ele eu mando o `window.location` para redirecionar a página, o problema e que a página e redirecionada entes do comando print. Preciso fazer o redirecionamento funcionar apenas quando o usuário imprimir ou cancelar a impressão.

Alguém pode me ajudar?
Segue meu código:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        // Remove o loading
        $(".se-pre-con").hide();

        // Remove Menu topo
        $(".header").hide();
        $('.content').css({
            top: ("0px")
        }).show();

        // Imprime a página
        window.print();

        // Redireciona página
        window.location = 'Logado.php?pagina=<?= $pagina_crypt ?>';
    });
```

Comment: `window.print()` é assíncrono, ele não vai aguardar a impressão.

Answer (score 1):

Pode tentar a função `setTimeout` para segurar:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        // Remove o loading
        $(".se-pre-con").hide();

        // Remove Menu topo
        $(".header").hide();
        $('.content').css({
            top: ("0px")
        }).show();

        // Imprime a página
        window.print();

        // Redireciona página após meio segundo
        setTimeout(function(){
             window.location = 'Logado.php?pagina=<?= $pagina_crypt ?>';
        }, 500);

    });
```

Comment: aumentei para `}, 1000);` e deu certo. Obrigado

Comment: Porem notei que ele demora 1000ms para redirecionar, após fechar a janela. Tem como o redirecionamento ser feito assim que o usuário fechar a janela?

Comment: @HugoBorges, Infelizmente só consegui isso ajustando o tempo, um pouco para mais ou um pouco para menos até checar à melhor configuração com esta implementação.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui uma solução melhor.

```js
        // Imprime a página
        window.print();
                
        (function () {
            var beforePrint = function () {
                
                // Remove o loading
                $(".se-pre-con").hide();

                // Remove Menu topo
                $(".header").hide();
                $('.content').css({
                    top: ("0px")
                }).show();
            };
            var afterPrint = function () {
                // Redireciona página
                window.location = 'Logado.php?pagina=<?= $pagina_crypt ?>';
            };

            if (window.matchMedia) {
                var mediaQueryList = window.matchMedia('print');
                mediaQueryList.addListener(function (mql) {
                    if (mql.matches) {
                        beforePrint();
                    } else {
                        afterPrint();
                    }
                });
            }

            window.onbeforeprint = beforePrint;
            window.onafterprint = afterPrint;
        }());
```

Fonte:
https://www.tjvantoll.com/2012/06/15/detecting-print-requests-with-javascript/

Comment: você testou no Google Chrome?

Comment: Esta implementação não é suportada pelo Chrome, nem pelo Opera e nem pelo Safari: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onafterprint

Comment: @AllanAndrade eu testei aqui e funcionou em todos os browser